# Git Branching - IOS App

Tags: iphone, git

I am planning to add my iOS project to GIT hub and I am new to the GIT branching and taging.
Please suggest a simple and good branching structure for development and production.

If i create one branch for development and one for production(master), is it possible to create sub branches under development?

Help is highly appreciable.

Comment: yes, you can create one branch for development and one for production(master). And there are number of tutorials for this. Let SO know what you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can branch from any commit in git. All branches are equal. Why don't you try it out?

SCM organisation tends to be project-specific, so, whatever works for you is good. Your clients should never see your entire repository anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, branching in Git is unlike branching in Subversion or any other Central VCS.
Guess you need one major branch, and from there you can make all possible branches you need. Just remember to merge what you want to keep.

E.g. you branch for production (guess solving problems (branch even per problem)) and you branch for development (sub branching again if needed). And later on you can combine (merge) the changes from the production branch back to the master and all the stuff from your development branches that you want to keep.

But there is no best way - that depends on your use cases.
I usually branch per problem (production / issues) and merge it back if solved.
The development branch(es) I only add when needed (f.i. before acceptance testing). 
YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a tarball named ios_project.tar.gz with your initial work. You can place it under git revision control as
follows.

```
$ tar xzf ios_project.tar.gz
$ cd project
$ git init
```

Git will reply
Initialized empty Git repository in .git/
You've now initialized the working directory--you may notice a new directory created, named ".git".

Let the master be as is. I would recommend you to create two branches one for development and another for production. Do all your code modifications which you are unsure of in your development branch, and when you are sure about your work, push it to the production branch and apply a tag on it so that it is each to track the production line at a later stage.

In addition to this if you would like to share it with others, then have the repository as a shared directory. And clone it on any other development machine, create a local branch tracking the development branch on this machine, do changes, push to origin.

Following set of commands would be useful at a very basic level:

```
git clone git@repository_path_on_network/folder_name
git branch usrname_activity_dev --track origin/branch_in_repository
git checkout usrname_activity_dev
git add filenames
git commit -m "comments"
git push origin usrname_activity_dev:branch_in_repository
git checkout local_production_branch
git rebase usrname_activity_dev
git push origin local_production_branch:production_branch_on_repo
git tag tag_name
git push origin local_production_branch:production_branch_on_repo  --tags
```

These are very basic commands. I would suggest you to further go through the internet. You will find a lots of commands according to every situation you are in.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Python scripts to help apply this are available [here](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow).